# .net 3.5 webclient issue: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: webclient

I'm trying to download a zip file from an external public server for [example](https://example.com/abc.zip): using `webclient.downloadfile()` method in a console application but i end up receiving the following error message:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

and

> "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

I tried several solutions but they did not help. I do not have control over the external server. When I manually browse the link on my browser I can download the file i.e. external server is fine but the issue is when downloading from console application. I'm using .Net Framework 3.5

I tried to place
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;` but that didnt work.
Please suggest

Comment: Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Any suggestion from someone?